# Copying files to S3 bucket using https

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, websphere-liberty

I am using AmazonS3Client to copy files to S3 bucket using https from java web application deployed on websphere liberty.

How can I configure the AmazonS3Client  to use custom jks file to import the ca certs.

I am getting error like

"com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Comment: If you are using a Java Web app, why are you not using the AWS SDK for Java V2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can use a custom JKS for AmazonS3Client, but can you add (via `keytool -import`) the Baltimore CyberTrust Root certificate to whatever JKS you are using?  That one is standard in most cacerts and is the trust anchor for S3.  I'm guessing that you are using a custom JKS.

Whatever you do, you should probably to update your application now for some certificate changes AWS has announced for S3.  See [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prepare-for-aws-move-to-its-own-certificate-authority/).